# Strikethrough different color than the text

Tags: strikeout

Using the cancel package, you can cross expressions in various ways.

However, what I can do to cross a symbol, with the strikethrough a different color, say red.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the command `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}`, described in the `cancel`documentiontation, section **2 Options**, page 1.

> If you use the color package, then you can declare
>
> `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{<color_command>}`
>
> and the cancellation marks will be printed in that color (e. g., \blue). However, if you are using color, I recommend lightly shaded blocks rather than diagonal arrows for cancelling.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc cancel`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel

It might sound tedious to look up the documentation for various small problems/features, but the package documentations tend to be well-written and easy to browse. Also, it will at the same time help you to understand how LaTeX works.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

  \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  2+2=\cancelto{4}{5}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```